# How to dynamically change the title of a website in react js (also in source code)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router, react-helmet

I tried the react-helmet.I used React router and I want to change the title when route changes. With react-helmet I was able to change the title in the tab and console but sadly not in the source. I want to change the title in the source code also as it is very important for seo.
**In /public/index.html**

```html
<title>My Title</title>
<meta name="description" content="This is main page"/>
```

**In src/app.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";
import {Helmet} from "react-helmet";
import Home from './Components/Pages/Home/';

function App() {
  return (
   <Router>
    <Helmet>
         <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <title>My title</title>
   <meta name="description" content="This is main page" />
        </Helmet>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/home">
          <Home></Home>
        </Route>
        </Switch>
        </Router>
        );
        }
        export default App;
```

**In Home.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import {Helmet} from "react-helmet";

function Home() {
  return (
  <div>
           <Helmet>
         <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <title>Home Title</title>
   <meta name="description" content="This is home page" />
        </Helmet>

  </div>
  );};
```

Comment: Hey, were you able to come up with a solution for this, or is SSR the only way?

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for SEO, then `create-react-app` is not the solution here.
Even if you share your page on social media, it won't show the metadata.
You have to do server-side rendering for that. To read about server side rendering, do check here

https://medium.com/@yudhajitadhikary/client-side-rendering-vs-server-side-rendering-in-react-js-next-js-b74b909c7c51

Answer (score 1):

Use React helmet to change your website title description. It also helps with SEO.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-helmet

```
import React from "react";
import {Helmet} from "react-helmet";
 
class Application extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
        <div className="application">
            <Helmet>
                <meta charSet="utf-8" />
                <title>My Title</title>
                <link rel="canonical" href="http://example.com" />
            </Helmet>
            ...
        </div>
    );
  }
};
```

Comment: As I mentioned earlier. I have added react helmet to the website. The title changes in the tab and console but not in the source code. And the source code is important for seo. So can you tell me how can I change the title in the sourcecode also?

Comment: Read the question again, to give an answer. @RS Sani

Comment: @Subreena I am pretty sure Google handles JavaScript-modified  titles properly for SEO purposes/

Answer (score 0):

You can change the title simply by doing `document.title = '...'`.

I put this in a `useEffect` for every top level component.

Google and Bing evaluate JS so will give no SEO disadvantage for setting the title in JS. However, other search engines might.

Answer (score 0):

you should use context in react ( useContext hook ) and in every page you will going to set that title in variable named pageTitle of something which is declared in your app context finally you can use helmet package and place it in your title tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from "react";
 
class Application extends React.Component {
   state={
   title:"dynamic title"
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    document.title = this.state.title
  }
  render () {
    return (
        <div className="homePage"></div>
    );
  }
}
```